# Spring 3.2 Dependency injection via @Resource for primitive types

Tags: java, spring

I have this Java code:

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl implements IGreetingService {

@Resource(name="abc")
private String anotherMsg = null;
```

What should be the spring-config.xml? The following xml is giving error:

> Error creating bean with name 'abc' defined in class path resource [greetingConfig.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'anotherMsg' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'anotherMsg' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

This is the bean configuration in spring-config.xml:

```xml
<bean id="abc" class="java.lang.String"> 
    <property name="anotherMsg" value="testing @Resource..."/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bean declaration

```
<bean id="abc" class="java.lang.String"> 
    <property name="anotherMsg" value="testing @Resource..."/>
</bean>
```

is for a bean of type `String`. The type `String` does not have a property called `anotherMsg`. Your class, `GreetingServiceImpl` has a property called `anotherMsg` (assuming it has the appropriate getters and setters).

If you really want to create a `String` bean, which you'll inject into a `GreetingServiceImpl` bean, use constructor arguments

```
<bean id="abc" class="java.lang.String"> 
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="testing @Resource..."/>
</bean>
```

You don't typically create `String` beans though. Use a property resolution instead to inject `String` values. Look into `@Value` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.